# Fastest URL to GET in order to check HTTP availability?

Tags: android, network-connection

I'm checking for HTTP availability in Android.  I'm sending an HTTP GET and using URL http://www.google.com.  This is my preferred method for actually sending the request.  The response is taking much longer than I would like.. sometimes as long as 5 seconds.  I would like it to be under 0.5 seconds.

All the questions I've found on here so far explain how to send HTTP GET requests, or how to check for network connectivity on the actual device.  I know how to do that.. I am just looking for a website that would basically load extremely fast.

I'm also asking on here because all of my Google search results are taking me to website speed testing pages like speedtest.net...

Is there a website / URL that I could send an HTTP GET request that would send me a response extremely fast??

Comment: There's never a guarantee of "extremely fast" when you are referring to mobile. There is no way to know what the network conditions may be when this GET request is sent off. If the network connection is poor, the response time will be longer then if the network connection is strong and on a 4G/LTE or fast WIFI network. What is the purpose of this request anyways?

Comment: separately, you might want a HTTP HEAD or even a HTTP OPTIONS ... but what level of availability are you looking for? internet availability in general, or whether HTTP is being blocked?

Comment: Yes, whether or not HTTP is being blocked... HTTP HEAD appears to be the same speed as HTTP GET for google.com

Answer (score 1):

You should do a HTTP `HEAD` request instead of a `GET`, that will almost always be faster given the server supports it.

I can confirm that

http://www.google.com

does respond to the HEAD request, so I would consider that ideal.